# iOS AFNetworking Synchronous Calls

Tags: ios, asynchronous, callback, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

I'm stuck in hole where I can't seem to progress without making a synchronous network call. Here is the code:

```
    __block NSInteger duration = 0;
    NSInteger index = [pathPoints indexOfObject:@(minutes)
                                  inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, pathPoints.count)
                                        options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual | NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        if ([obj1 class] == [CLLocation class]) {
            [OTGNetworkRequest fetchDistanceBetweenStart:self.startLocation andEnd:(CLLocation *)obj1 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSDictionary *json = responseObject;
                NSDictionary *element = json[@"rows"][0][@"elements"][0];
                duration = [element[@"duration"][@"value"] intValue];
            }];
                NSInteger seconds = [obj2 intValue] * 60;
                return [@(duration) compare:@(seconds)];
        } else {
            [OTGNetworkRequest fetchDistanceBetweenStart:self.startLocation andEnd:(CLLocation *)obj2 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSDictionary *json = responseObject;
                NSDictionary *element = json[@"rows"][0][@"elements"][0];
                duration = [element[@"duration"][@"value"] intValue];
            }];
            NSInteger seconds = [obj1 intValue] * 60;
            return [@(seconds) compare:@(duration)];
        }
    }];
```

So, the problem is I am trying to set duration, which requires a network call to Google Distance API. However, when I return the NSComparisonResult, duration is not set yet. How can I ensure that duration is set properly before I return? I can't put that in the success callback because the success callback block should not return anything.

Am I forced to use a synchronous network call or am I not working this through properly?

Comment: Calculate all of these distance measurements asynchronously up front. Once you have all the distances then perform your sort using a comparator which can now operate on data which is already available.

Comment: I wanted to avoid this and lazily get the distances, because otherwise I will sometimes end up making way too many calls to the API (pathpoints can contain 5000+ locations)

Comment: The docs for [`indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW31) state that: _The elements in the array must have already been sorted using the comparator cmp. If the array is not sorted, the result is undefined_. So it sounds like you'll need to have made all those network calls once already. Offhand, I can't think of a way around that.

Comment: The array should be sorted - I add the paths from shortest distance to longest, so I know that if I ask for the distance to a path later in the array, it will be longer. I fulfill all the criteria for a binary search - I just want to make a more efficient network call so I don't use up all my API requests.